# Help With JQuery On Menu

Tags: jquery, html, menu, fade, slide

Hey Im trying to make a menu with an embedded list that when hovered over will slide down the secondary lists or fade the lists in, Everything works so far I just need help with the JQuery for the effects. my html is:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h2>YEKTY</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>HOME</li>          
          <li>ABOUT US</li>          
          <li>WHO ARE WE?</li>
          </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h2>LINKS</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>YTU</li>
          <li>IPICCO ME</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h1>INFO</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>CONTACT</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

and the css is:

```
/******NAVIGATION******/
div#nav {
 width: 100%;
 background: transparent;
 float: left;
 text-align:center;
}

#nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 width:100px;
 padding: 0px;
 float: left;
 cursor:pointer;
}
#nav ul h1 {
 width:112px;
}
#nav a, #nav h2, #nav h1 {
 font: bold 11px/16px arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
}
#nav h2 {
 color: #fff;
 background: #000 url(images/nav_bg_flip.png);
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
#nav h1 {
 color: #fff;
 background:#000 url(images/nav_bg_flip.png);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 0 90px 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 90px 0;
 border-radius: 0 0 90px 0;
}
#nav a {
 color: #fff;
 background: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#nav a:hover {
 color: #fff;
 background: #a9a9a9;
}
#nav h2:hover {
 color:#fff;
 opacity:0.7;
}
#nav h1:hover {
 color:#fff;
 opacity:0.7;
}
#nav li {
 position: relative;
}
#nav li li a {
 opacity:0.7;
}
#nav li li a:hover {
 opacity:0.9;
 background:#464646;
}
#nav ul ul {
 position: absolute;
}
div#nav ul ul, div#nav ul li:hover ul ul{
 display: none;
}
div#nav ul li:hover ul{
 display: block;
}
/******END NAVIGATION******/
```

I do not need help with the CSS or HTML just the effects, there are links inside the `<li>` elements although I can not post that many. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$('#nav ul h2').hover(function() {
    $(this).nextAll('ul:first').slideDown();
}, function() {
    $(this).nextAll('ul:first').slideUp();
});
```

Assuming you want the `ul`'s to show when you hover over the `h2`'s of course ;)

Documentation for the hover function is here: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Edit: I meant to try this as well, but jsfiddle seems to be down or unreachable from where I am. I hope it works for you and I'll try it when I can.

EDIT: as suggested in the comments, this may work better:

```
$('#nav>ul>li').hover(function() {
    $('ul:first', this).slideDown();
}, function() {
    $('ul:first', this).slideUp();
});
```

Comment: I add that just as <script>
$('#nav ul h2').hover(function() {
    $(this).nextAll('ul:first').slideDown();
}, function() {
    $(this).nextAll('ul:first').slideUp();
});
</script> dont i? sorry im still pretty new to JQuery...

Comment: Yes, and don't forget to include the jQuery library as well :)

Comment: I think you need to edit your answer, put the hover effect on the `LI` container otherwise whenever he leaves the `h2` the menu will disappear!

Comment: Good point! See, this is what happens if you don't test your stuff. I edited my post, thanks.

Comment: Aaaah, that's it! I knew there was another one, I just didn't remember the name...